# TouchEvent with Display in android

Tags: android

Here's my code:

```
Display display;
.........
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
float x = event.getX();
float y = event.getY();     
int height = display.getWidth();
.........
}
```

Every time I include "int height = display.getWidth();" when testing my app. The program crashes. It seems every time I call a method from Display the app crashes.

Comment: From your code, i see that "display" is not initialized to anything. So, i guess its nullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

initialize display like below

```
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

Comment: I assume ctx is Context right? when loading the background it crashed. Btw, here is the new log cat.

Comment: : W/dalvikvm(326): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-06 14:59:30.011: E/AndroidRuntime(326): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 14:59:30.011: E/AndroidRuntime(326): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.proandroidgames/com.proandroidgames.SFGame}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 14:59:30.011: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
.......................